# Does the result of bitwise operations depend on endianess in Java? What about in C or C++?

Tags: java, c++, c, bitwise-operators, endianness

Consider the following code:

```
long store;
int firstValue = 0x1234;
int secondValue = 0x5678;
store = (((long) firstValue) << 32) | secondValue;
```

Is `store` guaranteed to have the value `0x12345678` regardless of the endianess of the machine...

- in Java?
- in C or C++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bitshift operations in all those languages operate on numbers. Endianness is not a property of numbers.

In Java `store` is guaranteed to have the value `0x123400005678L`, because `0x1234L << 32` is `0x123400000000L`.

In C and C++ `store` is not guaranteed to have any particular value: the result depends on the sizes of the types involved, and it has potentially undefined behaviour due to overflows (`long` is allowed to be as small as 32 bits, and it actually is so in some mainstream implementations). If no overflows occur, then the result is the same as in Java.

Comment: I meant a 32 shift of the long variable, I have edited the question fixing the mistake. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK in C it isn't even defined by the language how shift counts that do not fall inside 0 <= N < (operand bit size) work. And in java (0x1234 << 32) == 0x1234 (because 0x1234 is an int literal and shift count is modulo 32 (operand bit size).

Comment: @Durandal Regarding the C, are you talking about, maybe, overflows? Regarding the Java, that's quite the nitpicking; would it be ok if I removed the backticks (it's not longer code, and now we're back to numbers and not Java literals :P)?

Comment: C simply doesn't define how many of the lowermost bits of the shift count are actually *used*. int32 i = 1; i <<= 57; may shift by 57, 57 % 32 or something else, depending on implementation (compiler, platform). As for the  java case, it would be best to simply write 0x1234L (making clear its a long), if someone copy and pasted it as it is; it compiles but it doesn't give the value your explanation *says* it gives :)

Comment: Isn't that what undefined behaviour means?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes As I read your explanation, you mention "undefined" explicitly with regards to the value shifted. I see *nothing* addressing the shift count, but maybe I'm just overly sensitive to ambigous wording :)

Comment: A right operand that is too large always leads to a result that is too large. The standard might be extra explicit and call out the two situations, but there's no difference between them for signed types; one always causes the other (there is, however, a difference for unsigned types because operations on them never overflow). I feel that adding extra unnecessary wording will make the answer less valuable, not more. Thanks for the prefix suggestion, though.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean to shift by 16 bits, not 32, to get `0x12345678`. Shifting by 32 will overflow in Java, and in most C/C++ implementations.

That is guaranteed, and independent of endianness. Endianness determines how multi-byte values are stored in memory, not which bits are logically in which position within the value. Left-shifting by N bits is always equivalent to multiplying by 2<sup>N</sup>.

Comment: I meant a 32 shift of the long variable, I have edited the question fixing the mistake. Thanks

Comment: @Trollkemada: In that case, the result is `0x123400005678` in Java at least; in C/C++, `long` isn't guaranteed to be that large.

Answer (score 1):

Endianness doesn't matter, although whether the machine uses one's complement or two's complement can.

- In C, `<<` is unaffected because it is defined in terms of arithmetic operations (multiplication and exponentiation).
- In Java, `<<` is unaffected because it is defined in terms of arithmetic operations (multiplication, exponentiation, addition, arithmetic negation and subtraction).
- In C, `|` is defined in terms of the underlying bits. Endianness would have no effect, but it can behave differently on a ones' complement machine than on a two's complement machine.
- In Java, `|` is unaffected because Java integers are always two's complement.

I presume that C++ is the same as C.

Comment: multiplication by a power of two does not stop behave differently if you change the internal representation: as a trivial demonstration, the value of "3 * 16" is the same as the value of "three times sixteen". That I used "3" or "three" doesn't make it a different number.

Comment: @mafso that's an overflow (i.e. a multiplication that results in a number larger than the largest representable in the result type). No such a thing as a "sign bit" need to be involved.

Comment: C11 (n1570) 6.5.7 p.5 "The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2**E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."